# Woocommerce email notification

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

When my order changed its status from pending to proccessing no emails are trigger. I checked the plugin code

```
public function __construct() {

    $this->id               = 'customer_processing_order';
    $this->title            = __( 'Processing order', 'woocommerce' );
    $this->description      = __( 'This is an order notification sent to the customer after payment containing order details.', 'woocommerce'    );

    $this->heading          = __( 'Thank you for your order', 'woocommerce' );
    $this->subject          = __( 'Your {blogname} order receipt from {order_date}', 'woocommerce' );

    $this->template_html    = 'emails/customer-processing-order.php';
    $this->template_plain   = 'emails/plain/customer-processing-order.php';
    // Triggers for this email


    add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_processing_notification', array( $this, 'trigger' ) );
    // Call parent constructor
    parent::__construct();
}
public function trigger( $order_id ) {

    if ( $order_id ) {
        $this->object       = wc_get_order( $order_id );
        $this->recipient    = $this->object->billing_email;

        $this->find['order-date']      = '{order_date}';
        $this->find['order-number']    = '{order_number}';

        $this->replace['order-date']   = date_i18n( wc_date_format(), strtotime( $this->object->order_date ) );
        $this->replace['order-number'] = $this->object->get_order_number();
    }

    if ( ! $this->is_enabled() || ! $this->get_recipient() ) {
        return;
    }

    wp_mail( $this->get_recipient(), $this->get_subject(), $this->get_content(), $this->get_headers(), $this->get_attachments() );
}
```

I put a test mail in function to check this trigger function called or not . but in either it doesn't work. but other emails like forgot password, no stock email notifications are working fine only order status change mails are not working Sorry for my bad english. 
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the status manually, I'm not sure an email should be sent. But you can rather use the "Order Actions" on the right side to choose to send that email.
That will be a good test as well, choose the "New Order" to send the correct email. and wait for it.

[image]

If this doesn't help, recheck you email settings under WooCommerce and make sure the correct email is set under "New Order".

Comment: And in general, I really discourage any changes in the plugins' code. Everything you need to achieve should be coded under your customized child theme.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I am using paypal sanbox to check payments after payment complete. It should sent mail automatically right!. It won't sned any thing like that. But if I do try to send manually it trigger corresponding mail.

Comment: Did you set the IPN?
see here:
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/paypal-standard/#section-19
and here:
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/paypal-standard/#section-6